# Grails runtime exception: Could not open Hibernate session for transaction

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have developed a Grails web app and its on tomcat server right now. I am getting the following exception:

Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:

This occurs first time when someone tries to use the RESTful service for the day. The RESTful service works correctly after a first refresh and also works fine when subsequent requests are made.

Stacktrace is given below:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

```
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)

at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)

at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)

at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3333)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1971)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4997)

at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)

at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)

at $Proxy102.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)

......


at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)

at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)

at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:775)

at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:704)

at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:897)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Database Connection Pooling In Grails – solving the idle timeout issue](http://java.dzone.com/news/database-connection-pooling?utm_source=feedburner)

Answer (score 0):

We use the following in our DataSource.groovy to get around that issue. Check out the link @JamesA provided it seem to also have the needed information.

```
dataSource {
  ...
  properties {
    ...     
    // when to test
    testOnBorrow = true
    testWhileIdle = true
    testOnReturn = false
    // what to test with
    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
 }

}
```